# How to add additional attributes to User in Alfresco, like Passport No,Certifications, Blood Group etc.. and need to perform CRUD operations?

Tags: alfresco

How to add additional attributes to User in Alfresco,  like Passport No,Certifications,  Blood Group etc.. and need to perform CRUD operations also? 
I am new to alfresco, kindly give the info as elabarately. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog post](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/02/27/1555) explains how to do it in Alfresco 3.4d. The example will not work as-is for versions other than that, but you should be able to follow the same general process.

Comment: That blog explains it in the context of updating a user-profile. I however I'm trying to have the attributes added when a new user is created, that process seems to be entirely different (Currently looking into how I can do this). I might be wrong about this but there seems to be a contextual difference between a user and a person in alfresco and this seems to extend it's way down to the code also.